# Check if object property exists within a array of objects

Tags: arrays, angular, for-loop, object, ngfor

If I have the following array of objects:

```
abc: [ { id: 1, name: 'fred', lastName: 'curt' }, { id: 2, name: 'bill' }, { id: 2, username: 'ted', lastName: 'zapata' } ]
```

Is there a way to loop through the array on the HTML page using `*ngFor` to check whether a particular `lastName` property already exists or not?

for example:

```
<div *ngFor="let a of abc">
  <p>{{a.name}}</p>
  <p>//if a.lastName property is not present, show some message</p>
</div>
```

Comment: What about `<p *ngIf="...">`?

Answer (score 0):

You can check this using `*ngIf` and a `== null / != null` comparison. To avoid using two `*ngIf` with reversed statements, you can also make us of `ng-template`s with the `else` keyword.

```html
<div *ngFor="let a of abc">
  <p>{{a.name}}</p>

  <!-- display last name if it's defined, otherwise use the #noLastName template -->
  <p *ngIf="lastName != null; else noLastName">{{ a.lastName }}</p>

  <!-- template used when no last name is defined -->
  <ng-template #noLastName><p>a.lastName property is not present</p></ng-template>
</div>
```

Comment: Even more simple is to have `*ngIf="a.lastName` because a string will return false if empty, null or undefined and true if it has any value. Can be inverted by adding `!` as `*ngIf="!a.lastName`

Comment: Right. "property already exists" implies a null check though - so `''` could be a valid value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the [*ngIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) directive.

Code will look like this:

```html
<p *ngIf="a.lastName; else noLastName"> 
   /* If true it'll show everything between the p element*/
</p>
<ng-template #noLastName>
   /*If there's no last name, everything in the ng-template noLastName will be shown but it's not necessary to have an else case.*/
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can do something like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let a of abc">
  <p>{{a.name}}</p>
  <p>{{a.lastName || 'Different message'}}</p>
</div>
```